# Sound disabled on user login (works for guest and at login screen)

Tags: 12.04, sound, home-directory

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo Ultrabook U410.
Recently I changed the location of home directory to a bigger partition. I used rsync to copy the files and then edited fstab to auto-mount that partition.

Ever since, the sound in my user accounts has been disabled. I can see that sound works when the computer boots and login screen shows up. Even when I login as a guest, everything works fine. But the sound for the user profile is gone. I tried creating a new user profile, but got the same result.

The volume rocker in the sound settings is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your terminal:

```
rm -r ~/.pulse*; pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: I ran this command using sudo, but got this error... 
    
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory /home/penguin not ours.   
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Same situation here (15.04), after backup and restore /home.

I did:

```
rm -r ~/.pulse*; pulseaudio -k
```

and also had a "Permission denied". Then I realized that my home dir didn't belongs to me. After "chown" the sounds got back immediately.

I did:

```
chown user:user /home/user -R
```

Changing "user" to my username.